# Show which programs or libraries link against a specific shared library

Tags: linux, command-line, shared-libraries

I'm trying to find which program(s) or shared libraries link against a specific shared library on my system.  I'm a novice at the find command.  I guess I should say I know about ldd, but I am looking for an automated search.

Comment: It is actually related to your package manager; and a program could dynamically load other libraries (`dlopen`...)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 ldd program
```

It should  print out all necessary shared libraries